# Retrieving a photo from photo gallery

Tags: android

I have found this code and trying to implement in my application, it open the gallery, let's me select a photo, then the applications stops working and closes.

It's my first time trying to upload an image to mysql, and i'm stuck at the very beginning.

```
 buttonChoose.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)
            {
                showFileChooser();
            }
        });

 private void showFileChooser() {
        Intent intent = new Intent();
        intent.setType("image/*");
        intent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_GET_CONTENT);
        startActivityForResult(Intent.createChooser(intent, "Select Picture"), PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST);
    }




@Override
protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data) {
    super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);

    if (requestCode == PICK_IMAGE_REQUEST && resultCode == RESULT_OK && data != null && data.getData() != null)
    {
        Uri filePath = data.getData();

        try
        {
            bitmap = MediaStore.Images.Media.getBitmap(MainActivity.this.getContentResolver(), filePath);
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        imageView.setImageBitmap(bitmap);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Uri filePath = data.getData();
```

This will be meaningless for most `Uri` values.

The best solution to populate an `ImageView` from a `Uri` is by using [a third-party image loading library](http://android-arsenal.com/tag/46), such as [Picasso](http://square.github.io/picasso/).

If you insist upon doing this yourself, you will need to fork a background thread, use a `ContentResolver` and `openInputStream()` to get an `InputStream` on the content backed by the `Uri`, use `BitmapFactory` and `decodeStream()` to get a `Bitmap`, then (on the main application thread) update the `ImageView` with the `Bitmap`.

Comment: should it be done something like this ? 

            Uri imageUri = data.getData();
            Picasso.with(this).load(imageUri).into(imageView);

Comment: @jack: Yes, that looks fine, assuming that `this` is your `Activity`. That will handle loading the image on a background thread and putting it in your `ImageView`. There are lots of other configuration options on Picasso (e.g., scaling control), in case you need them.

Comment: well, the app stopped crashing, however nothing is being displayed on the imageView.... imageuri  = "content://media/external/images/media/182" ... does that sound right ?

Comment: @jack: That looks like a reasonable `Uri`. Check LogCat for errors. Also, make sure that you hold the `READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` or `WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE` permission, as that's needed on newer versions of Android. If your `targetSdkVersion` is 23 or higher, that also means that you need to deal with the whole runtime permission stuff, since those permissions are `dangerous`.

Comment: nice, thanks seems worked after adding the permissions. now to continue with the tutorial trying to upload the image to mysql server ...